# Is "Cycles X" just called Cycles in 3.0?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I just started using 3.0 on my PC and I haven't noticed dramatically faster rendering for any of my projects.

Render engine is just called Cycles.  Is that Cycles X, or is Cycles X still in beta?

How can I tell which version of Cycles I'm using?

Comment: Just seems to be 'Cycles' in 3.0 here and is over twice as fast as 2.93 on the simple scenes I've tried. Would be a lot faster still if I could justify a GPU that supported OptiX. :^(

Comment: Yes, cylces X was the name of the project under development

Comment: Ahh, copy, that makes sense.  Thanks Emir, if you want to make that an answer I'll mark it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cycles X was the name of the new Cycles Render engine during the development stage. Probably named "X" because of the Cycles 10th Annyversary ([SEE THIS](https://code.blender.org/2021/04/cycles-x/))

Comment: You do maintain the confusion by calling it a "new" one. It was never a new render engine, but instead a consequent rewriting project.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, Cycles X was the name that they assigned to it during development. In Blender, its simply cycles. Cycles X offers the most performance benefits on an Optix GPU, so if you render on a CPU you won't see as noticeable effects, but it should still be somewhat faster.